# Getting error using auto-layout, but looks good in simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

I'm trying to change the position of UIViews when the iPhone's orientation is changed. When the iPhone is in portrait mode, I want the `container view` to be one on top of the `tableView`. When in landscape mode, they should be side by side (`Container view`: left; `tableView`: right). I want to do this using `auto-layout`.

Here is an image of how I set it up: (Image is taken in: w Any h Compact.)

[image]

In the simulator, everything is working as expected. But when the iPhones orientation is changed, I get the following error:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f83f254b7d0 V:[UIView:0x7f83f2564230(272)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f83f251d9f0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f83f250c270]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f83f2564230]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f83f244bd00 UITableView:0x7f83f28c8e00.bottom == _UILayoutGuide:0x7f83f252f700.top>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f83f244bd50 V:[UIView:0x7f83f2564230]-(0)-[UITableView:0x7f83f28c8e00]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f83f254b880 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f83f250c270(64)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f83f24e4aa0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f83f250c270]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f83f2567df0 )>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f83f251d8e0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f83f252f700(49)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f83f2564300 _UILayoutGuide:0x7f83f252f700.bottom == UIView:0x7f83f2567df0.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f83f257dec0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7f83f2567df0(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f83f254b7d0 V:[UIView:0x7f83f2564230(272)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

The error is probably really simple, but I don't understand it. (Again, everything looks fine and normal in the simulator.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Image is taken in: w Any h Compact

But the problem is that when you switch to the other orientation, you are *not* in w:Any h:Compact. So at that moment, some of the grayed-out constraints spring to life! They are *conditional constraints*, based on the size class, i.e. the orientation.

So, you see that grayed-out constraint at the top of your screen shot, setting the container view height to 272? That's the problem! When you rotate the orientation, that constraint springs to life, and causes the conflict. So switch to whatever the size class is where that container view height constraint is *not* grayed-out, and think about *that* set of constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Why should it make problems if it disappears when in `w Any h Compact`? Also, I need the container views height to be 272 in that view. What can i do to fix that?

Comment: It makes problems only when it _appears_. When it does, it's just as Will M. told you: your constraints are over-determined and cannot all be satisfied simultaneously. As he hypothesized, you probably have a top constraint and a bottom constraints _and_ the height constraint, and that is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The error just means you had too many constraints, and some of them were colliding (impossible to fulfill). The system automatically ignored one of the colliding constraints (specifically the constraint that said the UIView was height 272). Even though it works fine for you, you should strive to fix it.

The problem is likely that you have distance constraints that span the entire height of the screen, so everything is constrained from top to bottom, but then you also have constraints defining a height, and the specific numbers are making it impossible for both of those to be fulfilled.

Comment: Beautifully explained.